# TASM struct initilization and pointer math issues

Tags: pointers, assembly, struct, tasm

I am attempting to write a simple DOS test program in assembly using TASM v4.1 that walks through a structure that contains four strings of equal length, but I've hit two issues.

```
    ideal
    model small
    stack 1024

struc Strings_s
s1  db 32 dup (?)
s2  db 32 dup (?)
s3  db 32 dup (?)
s4  db 32 dup (?)
ends Strings_s

    codeseg
start:
    mov     ax, @data
    mov     ds, ax                      ; Set %DS to point to the data segment
    mov     cx, 4                       ; Load loop count
    mov     si, offset mystrings.s1     ; Load seg offset of first string
start_1:
    push    si
    call    putstr                      ; Print asciiz string
    pop     si
    ;add        si, offset (Strings_s ptr ds:0).s1  ; ***BROKEN***
    add     si, offset (Strings_s ptr ds:0).s2  ; FIXED
    loop    start_1                     ; Loop
fin:
    mov     ax, 4C00h                   ; [DOS] terminate program
    int     21h                         ;  ...


putstr_0:
    mov     bx, 07h
    mov     ah, 0Eh                     ; [BIOS] Display character
    int     10h                         ;  ...
putstr: 
    lodsb                               ; Get next char from %SI
    test    al, al                      ; End of string?
    jne     putstr_0                    ;  no, loop
return: 
    ret                                 ; Return to caller


LF  equ 10
CR  equ 13

    dataseg
mystrings   Strings_s   <"One string","Two strings","Three strings","Four strings">


end start
```

The first issue is that I need to terminate the strings I'm declaring in the struct, but adding `,CR,LF,0` is misinterpreted as additional struct members and TASM doesn't see `\r\n\0` as escape sequences.

The second issue is that I'm trying to add the length Strings_s.s1 without hard coding 32 into my code.  I first tried using the `sizestr` directive on the struct member, but even with `version t300` defined before the `ideal` directive, TASM considers it an undefined symbol.  So then I tried the example I included using the offset and struct cast, but it ends up being encoded as `add si,0`.

Ideas?

EDIT: The second issue turned out to be a simple error.  You need to offset to the **second** member of the struct.  (code fixed)

EDIT2: The `sizestr` directive only works against text macros and is really just a simple strlen of the text after the `equ` directive, so it isn't what I thought it was.  I also tried slipping in a `Strings_len EQU $-Strings_s` between the s1 and s2 members, but it incorrectly equated to 23, not 32.

Comment: You should be able to use `foo equ 32` and use that everywhere (including in the definition of the struct), if you can't convince TASM to make its fancy syntax play nice with what you want to do.  Similarly for the crlf thing, you can always assemble the same bytes into memory with just plain `db` directives, using `align 32` (or `align foo`) to get to the start of the next struct element.  (If you align the start of the first one by 32).  Otherwise `db 32-($-bar)  dup (0)` might emit the right number of padding bytes, if I got the expression correct to calculate 32-len of the current one.

Comment: So I figured out the addition calculation error as soon as my head hit the pillow last night.  You have to offset to something inside the struct to get a non-zero value.  I'm still curious why the `sizestr` directive isn't working as it is clearer.  I could always change the struct definition to use `(0)` instead of `(?)`, which terminates the string, but I still need to get my line feed in there...